# Cookie Authentication without Identity Password

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies

I'm using the default individual user accounts template in Visual Studio 2017 asp.net core with my own custom user tables. `User` table has a `Password` and `LoginModel` has a `Password`. I've been following along [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie), for the `Login` in the `AccountController`.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model,
        string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == model.Email);
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email)
            };
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            await _httpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync
                (CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                principal, new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IsPersistent = model.RememberMe,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1)
                });
            return RedirectToRoute("HomePage");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

When I run the code, email will throw an error if I put in wrong one, but I can put whatever password I want and it'll be successful. How would I pull in the password to make sure it's the correct password?

Answer (score 0):

The password or a hashed version of it should be pass to the server Login controller action (via a secure HTTPS channel) and then it's up to you to validate it against your database, AD or whatever system you have in place before doing the SignInAsync. A dummy example with hardcoded password would be:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ContentResult> Login(string username, string password)
{
    if(username!="ADMIN" || password!="123")
        return new ContentResult { Content = "" };

    ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(
        new List<Claim>{
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
        },
        "cookies/ADMIN"));

    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(AdminAuthSchemeName, principal);

    return new ContentResult { Content = username };
}
```